# How to center and scale text in a textArea?

Tags: javascript, node.js, adobe, adobe-illustrator, extendscript

I'm trying to write an Adobe Illustrator script that takes in a name, then centers the name and scales it up to be as big as possible in a certain area. The name cannot spill onto a second line, and needs to work with up to 25 characters. Right now, my solution is seeing if a textArea spills into an overflow area, then scales the text accordingly, but this does not help with the line break issues. If anyone has any ideas as to what could make this work, that would be great.

```
var piRef = activeDocument.pathItems;
var textRefs = activeDocument.textFrames;

var pathRef = piRef.add();

// target text area
var textArea = piRef.rectangle(-50, 30, 60, 30);
var text = textRefs.areaText(textArea);

var maxFontSize = 200

text.textRange.characterAttributes.size = maxFontSize;

// create an overflow box
var overflowArea = piRef.rectangle(-50, 30, 60, 30);
var overflowText = textRefs.areaText(overflowArea, TextOrientation.HORIZONTAL, text);

text.contents = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy";

// shrink text size until the overflow box is empty.
var fontSize = maxFontSize;
while (overflowText.words.length > 0 && fontSize > 0 ||)
{
    text.textRange.characterAttributes.size = --fontSize;
    overflowText.textRange.characterAttributes.size = --fontSize;
}
```

This is my current code for testing, and it scales the text unevenly and also has line breaks. I am not sure how to make it work for many different word lengths.

Comment: this is just a guess, but what happens if you change the order of the last two lines `text.textRange.characterAttributes.size = --fontSize;` and `overflowText.textRange.characterAttributes.size = --fontSize;`

Comment: The `TextRange` object has the collection `lines`. https://ai-scripting.docsforadobe.dev/jsobjref/TextRange.html#textrange-lines You can check the length of the collection and keep to decrease the font size until `lines.length == 1`

Answer (score 0):

It can be done this way:

```
var piRef = activeDocument.pathItems;
var textRefs = activeDocument.textFrames;

var pathRef = piRef.add();

var textArea = piRef.rectangle(-50, 30, 60, 30);
var text = textRefs.areaText(textArea);

// set size of the text to 1 pt
text.textRange.size = 1;

text.contents = "abcde fghijklmnopq rstuvwxy";

// scale the size up until it gets 2 lines
while (text.textRange.lines.length < 2) text.textRange.size += .1;

// make one step back to get 1 line
text.textRange.size -= .1;
```

It sets minimal size for the text first and makes it bigger until it gets two lines. Then it changes the font size back.

Another approach is to check if an amount of characters in the first line of the `textRange` is the same as an amount of characters in the `textRange`.

Here is the implementation (a little bit more robust and accurate than above):

```
var piRef = activeDocument.pathItems;
var textRefs = activeDocument.textFrames;

var pathRef = piRef.add();

var textArea = piRef.rectangle(-50, 30, 60, 30);
var text = textRefs.areaText(textArea);

text.textRange.size = 1;
text.contents = "a bcde fghijklmnopq rstuvwx y";

change_size(text.textRange, 1);   // rough
change_size(text.textRange, .1);  // fine
change_size(text.textRange, .01); // super-fine

function change_size(range, step) {
    while (range.lines[0].characters.length == range.characters.length)
        range.size += step;
    range.size -= step;
}
```